# How to use python Multiprocessing to update dict and set correctly?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

I want to go though loop and update dict and set inside class using function. If i am correct Multiprocessing.Manager will not help me because it only merges the result at the end.

I wrote a toy exmaple to understand how it works.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook

class MyClass():
    D = {}
    S = set()
    def func(self, l):
        for i in l:
            if i not in self.D:
                self.D[i] = [i]
            else:
                self.D[i].append(i)
            self.S.add(i)

cl = MyClass()
b = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10**8)
spl_b = np.array_split(b, 15)
pl = ThreadPool(5)
with pl as p:
    list(tqdm_notebook(p.imap(cl.func, spl_b), total = 15))
pl.close()
pl.terminate()}
```

So when i run this code using Pool it outputs empty dict and set and with ThreadPool it use only 1 cpu, but output everything correctly. What can i do to use several CPUs to update and check class objects?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, what you're asking, but you might want to have a look into `multiprocessing` queues to pass data around.

Comment: Can u pls show how to combine queue and dict. Should i put in queue sequence of opperation on dict or what?